# Number increment animation while scrolling ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, uiview

I have a `UILabel` which will contain a number that needs to be animated to increment to a given value from zero. The label is placed inside an `UITableView` and is subview of an `UITableViewCell`. For some weird reason my numbers wont animate while the view is scrolling. If I pause the scrolling numbers animate. Why is that so and how to fix it?

Approach 1 which fails:

```
NSInteger fromValue = 0;
NSInteger toValue = 57; //In this example toValue has to be greater than fromValue
NSString *suffix = @"K";
NSTimeInterval interval = 0.016; //Adjust for different animation speed
NSTimeInterval delay = 0.0;
for (float i = fromValue; i <= toValue; i++)
{
    NSString *labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.3f%@", i, suffix];
    [numberLabel1 performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:labelText afterDelay:delay];
    delay += interval;
}
```

The second one was to use [UICountingLabel from Giuthub](https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel) which offers the same functionality but also doesnt work. Why? How to fix? My code of using it looks like:

```
UICountingLabel *numberLabel1 = [[UICountingLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 105, winSize.width / 2, 40)]; //winSize is 
numberLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
numberLabel1.method = UILabelCountingMethodLinear;
numberLabel1.format = @"%.3f";
[numberLabel1 countFrom:0 to:num1.floatValue withDuration:countDuration];
```

Any other way on how to make this "tick"? I need this animation to be able to scroll really badly.

Cheers, Jan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UICountingLabel` method can work. The problem is the run loop mode that the timer is attached to is the default run loop mode, and it doesn't run while a scroll is in progress. If you modify the timer so it is in the `NSRunLoopCommonModes` then it will fire and the label will update during scrolling.

---

Line 137 in UICountingLabel.m, replace `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` with `NSRunLoopCommonModes`.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that as well please?